# Win32 API: How to clip siblings using GetDCEx()?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I have 3 overlapping child static controls where I need to do a solid fill in IDC_STATIC2:

[image]

I do that as follows:

```
HWND hwndCtl = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC2);
HDC hdc = GetDCEx(hwndCtl, NULL, 
                  DCX_CACHE | DCX_CLIPSIBLINGS); // clip siblings above IDC_STATIC2
RECT rc{};
GetClientRect(hwndCtl, &rc);
HBRUSH hbr = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,150,150));    
FillRect(hdc, &rc, hbr);

DeleteObject(hbr);
ReleaseDC(hdc);
```

This is what I expect:

[image]

However, I get the following result where IDC_STATIC1 is clipped out instead of IDC_STATIC3:

[image]

This is the quote from MSDN for using `DCX_CLIPSIBLINGS` flag of `GetDCEx()`:

> Excludes the visible regions of all sibling windows *above* the window
>   identified by *hWnd*.

The behavior I get is the opposite. IDC_STATIC3 is **above** IDC_STATIC2 but it is **not** excluded from visible region(I can draw on it). IDC_STATIC1 is **below** IDC_STATIC2 but it is excluded from visible region.

Is there a way to make this work as stated in MSDN? Or am I interpreting it wrong?

Comment: If you have created the controls in the order they are numbered, the result you see would be correct. A child window is created at the **bottom** of the z-order by default. So `IDC_STATIC3` would actually be **below** `IDC_STATIC2`. See remarks of [`CreateWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx) about the z-order.

Comment: @zett42 : I created the static controls in numbered order, but in resource editor, not with CreateWindow(). As for the z-orders, how can z-order of IDC_STATIC3 be below IDC_STATIC2 if IDC_STATIC3 is drawn **over** it? Doesn't z-order determine which window is drawn above the other? The strange thing is that setting WS_CLIPCHILDREN of all the static controls seems to reverse the draw order as you suggest.

Comment: The dialog manager calls `CreateWindow` under the hood, so what I wrote also applies to the creation order in resource editor. _Doesn't z-order determine which window is drawn above the other?_ - There is no defined drawing order by default (unless `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` is used). If a window that has not `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` set, gets invalidated, it will just be redrawn in place regardless of z-order.

Answer (score 1):

When you create static controls using CreateWindow/CreateWindowEx, must use WS_CLIPSIBLINGS style for get that effect.

Or, if you use resource editor, you must set TRUE "clip siblings" style in CHILDS's windows properties.

I am not sure about DCX_CLIPSIBLINGS flag usage, but i think is not required

Comment: Setting `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` flag for all static controls **and** using `DCX_CLIPSIBLINGS` in `GetDCEx()` does work as expected. Setting `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` flag for the **parent window** seems to have no effect.

Comment: `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` affects sibling windows of the window with the style set, so this is the expected behaviour.